# DISCORD.JS SendPing to Host

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm developing a bot in Discord.js, and because I use lavalink, I hosted it (lavalink server) on a free host, and to keep it online I need to do some pings constantly, I was wondering if, is there any way to make my bot (which is currently my vps) send a ping every time interval to the "url/host" where my lavalink is. if you have any solution I will be grateful!

Comment: Maybe `setInterval` may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways:

## Using Uptimer Robot (fastest way)

Uptimer Robot is an online service that can do HTTP requestes each 5 minutes.
Very simple and fast to use, see more [here](https://uptimerobot.com/).

## making the request from your bot vps

#### Installing node-fetch

Type this in yout terminal:

```
npm i node-fetch
```

#### Making the request

Insert this where You want in the bot code.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const intervalTime = 300000; // Insert here the interval for doing the request in milliseconds, like now 300000 is equal to 5 minutes
const lavalinkURL = 'insert here the lavalink process url';
setInterval(() => {
    fetch(lavalinkURL);
}, intervalTime)
```